# Compare text in Excel columns and then assign corresponding value to specific column

Tags: excel, text, multiple-columns

I have some values in Excel worksheet i.e. values in column B, D and E are:

```
**B**                       **C** **D**       **E**

Cryptography                  11    1         Applied Mathematics
Machine Learning              23    2         Analysis of Algorithms
Networks and Communication    26    3         Automata Theory
Networks and Communication    26    4         Artificial Intelligence
Robotics                      30    5         Biological Networks
Computer Graphics             10    6         Combinatorial Optimization
Data Mining                   12    7         Computability Theory
Combinatorial Optimization    6     8         Computational Complexity Theory
Applied Mathematics           ..    9         Computer Vision
Analysis of Algorithms        ..    10        Computer Graphics
Information Retrieval         ..    11        Cryptography
Artificial Intelligence       ..    12        Data Mining
Artificial Intelligence       ..    13        Data Structures
Programming Languages         ..    14        Databases
Data Mining                   ..    15        Digital Logic
Cryptography                  ..    16        Distributed Computing
Information Retrieval         ..    17        Evolutionary Computation
Machine Learning              ..    18        Human Computer Interaction
Machine Learning              ..    19        Image Processing
...                           ..    ..        ...
...                           ..    ..        ...
...                           ..    ..        ...
```

whereas `column C` is empty.

Now I have to match values from `column B` with `column E`, the row where the match found, I have to copy the corresponding ID from `column D` and place it into the `column C`. Whereas I have put some values manually in `column C` for a quick idea.

Comment: VLOOKUP is what you're looking for.  Basically, you give the ranges for what to lookup, compared to what, and return whatever value.  This is exactly what it's for.

Comment: @durbnpoisn - in this instance, `Vlookup()` probably isn't the most straighforward choice, without OP changing his data around.  The table range for the `Vlookup()` will start with what he wants to return (col. D) and _then_ is the range for his lookup.  He'd have to switch columns D and E around first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, an Index/Match formula (a little more powerful than Vlookup) should work fine:

`=INDEX($D$1:$D$19,MATCH($B1,$F$1:$F$19,0))`.  ENTER and drag down.  Note to change the `19` to the last row of your data ranges.

This will return an index, being a cell in range `D1:D19`.  It'll first though look to range `F1:F19` for a match of the value of cell `B1`, and get that row, then use that row in the `Index()` to return the value.

Edit: You can wrap this in an `Iferror()` function to output some text if there's an error.  I.e. `=IfError(INDEX($D$1:$D$19,MATCH($B1,$F$1:$F$19,0)), $B1 & " not found")`

Edit2: Why didn't I use vlookup, if they're comprable?  Because the way you have your data laid out currently doesn't really allow for it (easily, anyways).  Try to set it up yourself and you'll see: `=Vlookup(B1,d1:F19,1)`...doesn't make sense.  You'd need to rearrange your data first, and put the column D numbers in G, then this one would work: `=VLOOKUP(B1,F1:G19,2,FALSE)`

Comment: @BruceWayne--Thank you very much

Comment: @user5313087 - you're welcome! Your question is actually a really good demonstration of some limitations of `Vlookup()` and shows how you can use the more "powerful" Index/Match to do basically the same thing, only with more flexibility.

Comment: @BruceWayne--Thanks once again